# Using Swagger with Flask

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to generate a RESTful API in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) using [Swagger](http://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/)?

Comment: There is [this](https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger) if the API already exists or [this](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) to *generate* one.  As such though, this is very much a "suggest to me a library" question, which is much more appropriate for [chat]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flask is now supported from the Swagger Editor: http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Answer (score 17):

There is [Flask-RESTPlus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus) based on Flask-Restful until now.
It provides some decorators to document your API and generate a Swagger specification, a Postman collection...

Next version will be able to generate the API from Swagger specifications.

Comment: This is a great choice, it works just like restify, but includes swagger, and it includes the swagger UI.

Comment: I only wish that @api.doc(...) and other Swagger doc decorators in Flask-RESTPlus 0.12 were documented better. I am spending HUGE time shooting in the dark to get the doc like I want it.

Comment: There is an entire documentation page only for the documentation decorators: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html
If something is unclear or missing, please submit pull-requests (or ask)

Comment: Thing is, to PR with the bits that are unclear and or missing, you need to know what the solution is. I spent ages earlier trying to make a field a password type input. Random things like that. Oh and trying to have an API spread across more than 1 file. Don't get me wrong this is my answer of choice for this problem, but it's sometimes harder than it should be to achieve things

Comment: **IMPORTANT** to note that the Flask-RESTPlus project should be considered unmaintained and been forked to another side project.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [connexion](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/connexion)

"Connexion is a framework on top of Flask to automagically handle your REST API requests based on Swagger 2.0 Specification files in YAML."

Comment: Connexion is based on OpenAPI 2.0 Specification.  This is disappointing as OpenAPI has since moved on to 3.0!

Comment: Connexion 2 was recently released - it claims to implement OpenAPI 3.0.  I found it adheres to the spec more closely if `connexion.App()` is defined with `options={'uri_parsing_class': OpenAPIURIParser }` param

Answer (score 4):

You can use [flask-restful-swagger](https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger).

Answer (score 3):

Flasgger is an extension to make automatic UI for Flask routes  http://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the [flask-restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension you could take a look at [flask-sillywalk](https://github.com/hobbeswalsh/flask-sillywalk)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there is also [flask-apispec](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec). It uses marshmallow to write the schemas/annotations that end up in the swagger output.

Answer (score 1):

For Swagger 3.0:

Use [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com).

Comment: This may not be a correct answer (technically it uses Starlette instead of Flask), but it is IMHO by far the best. I tried all the other options and was dismayed that they fail to take advantage of modern Python. In contrast, the serialization, typing and routing with FastAPI are beautifully implemented, and being actively improved. Starlette is very similar to Flask, so there is barely any learning curve.